# Spring JDBCTemplate vs Plain JDBC for inserting large numbers of records

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

We have to insert 2 millions of records across multiple tables and right now we are writing into a CSV file and using db2 import to load into database.

We wanted to change this logic to some kind of JDBC. While looking into multiple options, I am confused with Spring JDBC template and plain JDBC.

Let us say I wanted to insert 1 million records into 10 tables, each of which will have 100 thousand, and all these are simple JDBC statements (not prepared statements because I don't know which table I am dealing with at runtime).

Whatever system we choose will need to handle inserting up to 15 million records for a peak request.

Which framework will be better?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to move a lot of data, then using JDBC (or any library building on top of JDBC) may be a bad choice, compared to using bulk copy tools (like db2import). JDBC is going to be orders of magnitude slower, because

- JDBC is a very chatty protocol, and
- usually bulk copy tools relax constraints during the copy process.

The difference in time can be extreme: what takes the bulk copy tool 10 minutes can take hours using JDBC. You'll want to create a prototype and do some timings and be certain about what kind of performance you'll get before you commit to something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using Spring, then you may as well use `JdbcTemplate`. It makes things a bit easier, and in some simple cases means you need not use the JDBC API directly yourself.  Essentially, `JdbcTemplate` is a very thin wrapper around JDBC that removes some of your annoying boiler-plate code.

Comment: But after looking into this http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-59970.html I feel like spring jdbc is slow...

Comment: @sanumala: I can't say I've ever found it to be particularly slow, but why not try it and see if it's suitable for you in terms of performance? Premature optimisation is evil, and all that.

Comment: @sanumala: You feel it's slow based on a 2 year old third-party opinion?

Comment: @GaryF I wanted to try both but dont know in terms of millions of inserts not sure how to handle if something goes wrong ... let me try spring jdbctemplate first coz we are already using spring.. will keep posted..

Answer (score 2):

As skaffman said, if you are already using Spring then your choice is probably `JdbcTemplate`. Specifically you may want to look at the `batchUpdate()` method. [Here is a pretty good example of how it works](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/). I've used it to insert a couple hundred thousand rows quickly with great success.

Comment: I have used batch update in my applications, but this is kind of differnt requiremnet, I am writing spring logic let us see how it works...

Answer (score 0):

Consider [JdbcSession](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc/apidocs/com/jcabi/jdbc/JdbcSession.html) from [jcabi-jdbc](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc/). It's as simple as JDBC should be, for example (inserting a million records):

```
JdbcSession session = new JdbcSession(source);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
  session.sql("INSERT INTO foo (number) VALUES (?)")
    .set(i)
    .insert(new VoidHandler());
}
```

That's it.